# Secondary accent color in WPF using Material Design

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I have a button using accent style

```
 <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="90" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Alert" Height="40" Width="40" />
            </Button>
```

But I want this specific button to use a red accent style and not my default accent which is lime.

This will only happen in this specific window.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redefine the secondary accent brush in the resources of your button

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="90" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="#F44336"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="#E57373"/>
    </Button.Resources>

    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Alert" Height="40" Width="40" />
</Button>
```

I hope it can help you.